# adding a line <hr> in returned for each results

Tags: html, css

I am appending data to the screen, but at the end of each I am trying to add a `<hr>` which produces a line. The issue is, when I add this simple tag, it messes up the structure. I am not sure what is causing this, but I would like to know how to append the tag without stretching out all of the appended elements.

```js
$.each(results, function() {
  $("#resultsDiv").append('<tr>');
  $("#resultsDiv").append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center">' + this.group1 + '</td>');
  $("#resultsDiv").append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center">' + this.group2 + '</td>');
  $("#resultsDiv").append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center"><img id="Img" src="ghost.png"></td>');
  $("#resultsDiv").append('<hr>');
  $("#resultsDiv").append('</tr>');
});
```

```html
<div id="resultsDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Just use `border-bottom:1px solid black` - you can omit the last child with CSS if needs be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely add a row that has just an `<hr>` in it. (Although, as other's have said, I would seriously consider using CSS instead; I won't address that here).

Example HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="results">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Ipsum</td>
        <td><img src="ghost.png"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="999"><hr></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it looks like there are some other issues with your code. You need to give complete elements (open and close tag) to JQuery's `append()` function or else it'll automatically close off any element (for more information, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824101/jquery-append-opening-and-closing-a-tag)).

Example JS after cleanup (Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn9mxwcv/)):

```
$.each(results, function () {
            var $tr = $('<tr>')
                .append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center">' + this.group1 + '</td>')
                .append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center">' + this.group2 + '</td>')
                .append('<td width=11.1% align="left" valign="center"><img  src="ghost.png"></td>')

            var $trSep = $('<tr>')
                .append('<td colspan="99"><hr></td>');

            $dest.append($tr)
                .append($trSep);
        });
```

As a side note, please consider using a templating library to construct HTML ([Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) is awesome). This is much more maintainable than building JS / jQuery HTML structures.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look here [Using an `<hr>` tag with a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522337/using-an-hr-tag-with-a-table)

relevant quote from @marcianx

> The best way to add a horizontal line between rows is with CSS borders

and I agree.